# How to set the picture title locally small in latex?

Tags: latex, local, font-size

I have been stuck trying to change the local size of a picture title.
The picture is like this. The "EnlightenGAN" is just too long. I would want to make "EnlightenGAN" smaller only.
[This is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HKWW.png)

the code is here:

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
    \label{fig:example}
    \begin{subfigure}{.194\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/exdark/原图/2015_00001.png}
        \caption{输入图片}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.194\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/exdark/dupe/2015_00001.png}
        \caption{Deep-UPE\upcite{DUPE}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.194\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/exdark/lime/2015_00001.jpg}
        \caption{LIME\upcite{LIME}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.194\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/exdark/mir/2015_00001.jpg}
        \caption{MIRNet\upcite{MIRNet}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.194\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/exdark/retinex/2015_00001.jpg}
        \caption{RetinexNet\upcite{retinexnet}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.194\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/exdark/ssien/2015_00001.jpg}
        \caption{SSIEN\upcite{ssien}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.194\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/exdark/zeroDCE/2015_00001.jpg}
        \caption{Zero-DCE\upcite{zero}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.194\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/exdark/enlightenGAN/2015_00001.png}
        \small
        \caption{EnlightenGAN\upcite{enlightengan}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.194\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/exdark/kind/2015_00001.jpg}
        \caption{KinD\upcite{KinD}}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.194\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{figures/exdark/mine/2015_00001.png}
        \caption{本文}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{增强结果}
\end{figure}
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this problem!

Comment: please make a small, but compilable test document

Comment: In particular we need to know which of the several packages that provide an `subfigure` environment you are using.